# session variable in TASK

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am using Task library to create background process in `asp.net` application
once Task completes it updates the result in session variable.

Then I am reading from the session variable.I noticed the session result are not unique to the session
if I open different browser and test it session result has the values from other session also.
Is there a way how to handle this.

Comment: Are you expecting the same result as final out put??

Comment: Just before you continue with implementing your solution make sure you have read the following article: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx because the notion of Tasks stinks badly in an ASP.NET application as you will learn from that article.

Comment: HI humpty,the result will be different each session I am passing diferent parameter.